# How do I make Python 3.4 output my randnum to a text file?

Tags: python

Please keep in mind I am new to programming. I am trying to make a Guess the Number kind of game and want to export the random number to a text file. I don't want it to overwrite the numbers everytime, I just want it to put a new number in there every time, but I don't know how to write the number to a .txt file. Any help? Here's my code:

```
def easy():
    print ("")
    print ("Difficulty: Easy")
    print ("")
    irand = randrange(1,10)
    with open("GTN.txt", "a") as text_file:
        text_file.write(irand + "\n")
    while True:
        number = input("Pick a number 1 - 10: ")
        try:
            number = int(number)
        except ValueError:
            print("    ")
            print(number, 'is not a number, try again.')
            continue
        if number > irand:
            print("That's too high, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number < irand:
            print("That's too low, try again.")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(1)
        elif number == irand:
            print("    ")
            print("You got it right! You won!")
            print("    ")
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: So you are  already able to write numbers as i see but you want your file to contain unique numbers each time you write new random numer to it ?

Comment: @Tanveer Alam Yes, that's pretty much what I want to do.

Comment: Well as you have opened your file in append mode and randrang(1,10) can give you 9 unique values after that it will start writing duplicate numbers in your file. But it seems you have already accepted the answer.

Comment: @TanveerAlam I'm alright with it writing duplicate answers. I just want to see how often it uses certain numbers. I also added the feature for anyone who wants to cheat on the game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to cast `irand` from an `int` to a `str`, apart from that your code is fine:

```
   text_file.write(str(irand) + "\n")
```